# Scan uploaded files for malwares under Windows using PHP

Tags: php, security, file-upload

I'm trying to install ClamAV on Windows but I can't find how to.

What I want actually is to scan for malwares uploaded files and return a value like "safe" or "Infected by: X"

Do you think it's possible on Windows using a free library?

Do you know if there is a paid software that can do this (even using command-line)?

Comment: PHP and Malware scanning?  The phrase 'horses for courses' springs to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it by installing ClamWin on the Windows 2008 Server. (clamwin-0.97.6). I created the **eicar.txt** file in order to test detection:

```
X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*
```

Created **test.php** file:

```
<?php
$file = 'C:/Users/Localadmin/Desktop/testfile/eicar.txt'; // infected test file
$db = '"C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/.clamwin/db/"'; // path to database of virus definition
$scan_result = shell_exec("D:/programs/clamwin/bin/clamscan --database=$db $file"); 
echo $scan_result;
?>
```

It gives me this result:

```
Eicar-Test-Signature FOUND

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 1568163
Engine version: 0.97.6
Scanned directories: 0
Scanned files: 1
Infected files: 1
Data scanned: 0.00 MB
Data read: 0.00 MB (ratio 0.00:1)
Time: 7.363 sec (0 m 7 s)
```

Than you can process the string **$scan_result** to figure out what number has been returned after *'Infected files: '*.

I will be using it to scan files uploaded via form and since the scanning takes time (7 seconds) I will use some ajax script which can nicely return feedback to the user such "*Uploading file...*" and "*Scanning for viruses...*"

Comment: Thanks Arturito for your answer! I'm going to use your way ;)

Comment: @user3784251 I used the returned string and used PHP to analyse/split the result. It's messy but it works. If you still need help for your specific issue, you should open a new question ;) Good luck!

Comment: To make this faster you should run clamd.exe (ClamAV Daemon) on the server, and scan with clamdscan.exe. Clamscan loads the database every time its run and is thus much slower. Clamd loads the database once and then clamdscan uses the pre-loaded database.

Answer (score 1):

You can install clamav for windows (clamwin), and use php's passthru function to scan a file via commandline and get the output back.  Parse it then display your message.  You will have to adjust your php timeout value, or configure your application to upload, get the user to constantly refresh for the status while a background script scans and inserts the result into a database or something.  Try looking at virustotal.com they do this, and scan it with over 20 av scanners.

Comment: Thanks for the hint,but since 2 hours I'm trying to know commands I can use with ClamAV (lastest 2.0 version) but I can'T find any informations... including the official website... any idea?

Comment: Have you tried C:\Program Files\ClamWin\bin>clamscan {yourfile} ?

Comment: There is no Bin folder on my installed version of ClamAv :S -- Edit -- Okay I installed ClamAv not ClamWin, I'll try installing ClamWin, I'll give you update. Thanks!

Comment: LOL, my PHP code return me "0". Here is my code : passthru('".\\ClamWin\\bin\\ClamWin.exe" --mode=scanner --path="D:\\list_of_movies.xlsx" --log="c:\clamavlog.txt" --close', $array); print_r($array);