# scan uploaded file for virus in user's machine using php

Tags: php, security, file-upload, antivirus, malware

Is there any way to scan the file uploaded by user in their machine using PHP?

I am creating a website using PHP, where I give users the privilege to upload files of any format. Now I want to scan the files uploaded by the users for any virus or malware. Also I want to scan it before placing it in the server.

Is there any Online sites available to scan those files? Or give me any other best way to achieve this.

I am using Xampp (phpmyadmin) in Windows.

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful resource you can use for free: [virustototal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/en/faq/#virustotal-api)
They have API to include in your PHP scripts as well.

The other option is to use ClamAV, but I'm not perfectly sure about this.

Comment: will you please provide me any tutorial link of how to install and use it.

Comment: The official documentation is the best tutorial, I guess: [tutorial link](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/#getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

"ClamAV is a free anti virus commonly used on server applications.

php-clamav is an extension for binding ClamAV to PHP. You can check their documentation." 
from [What are my options to check for viruses on a PHP upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660260/what-are-my-options-to-check-for-viruses-on-a-php-upload)

Comment: May i know how to install and use clamav in windows??

Comment: You see, this should have been mentioned in the description :)
Then either use the virustotal API or check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130203/scan-uploaded-files-for-malwares-under-windows-using-php