# In PHP, how to check for virus when uploading files?

Tags: php, virus-scanning

Is there some library or way to scan for virus in PHP, when user upload a file in a web page?

Comment: Check out the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456896/scan-uploaded-file-for-virus-in-users-machine-using-php

Comment: What operating system do you wish for this to run on?

Answer (score 0):

You could execute a command line scan, send it to a third party api to test for viruses or let an active scanner on your server handle it.   It just depends on what operating system your server runs, file type and how thorough you want to be to determine the right solution.

Comment: OP: I'd pair this with a job server, like Gearman. You can send a signal to Gearman to start a job, which then fires up a worker (written in whatever language you like) to kick off the virus scan.

Comment: Like I said, lots of ways, just depends on personal preference/requirements